# MySQL: get only non-null columns

Tags: mysql, null

There is table:

[image]

I need to get the non-null columns with where "column"-specified value.

Try this

```
select * from table where category='1-137-2891' and defence is not null and type is not null
```

but obviously get the empty set.

Comment: defence and type _are_ NULL for _all_ rows that are shown in your screenshot – so what do you want?

Comment: I need to get all columns which are not null

Comment: specify them explicitly

Comment: Either you select a column in the column list after SELECT, or you don’t – you can not base that decision on the column values.

Comment: Just wander why do you need such fancy query?

Comment: It's not mine. Need to provide fix for web app DB of that I can't change.

Comment: I've updated my answer, but still not sure it's good idea to have such 
peculiar queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I've got an answer for you.

Suppose you've got table like this:

```
create table t (a int, b int);
insert into t (a, b) values (1, null);
```

Then, you can create dynamic SQL statement and execute it with EXECUTE command;

```
set @sql = (select concat('select ',
case when sum(a) is null then '' else 'A' end,
case when sum(b) is null then '' else ', ' end, 
case when sum(b) is null then '' else 'B' end,
              ' from t')
from t);

prepare stmt FROM @sql;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

[Here is an example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9ac5f/17)

Answer (score -1):

SELECT * FROM table WHERE ('data1' is not null)